# Kivy - duplicate class instance on super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Immediately after the super() function is called, it creates a duplicate WidgetClass instance.

My understanding of the super() I've used is that it refers to the EditImageLayout class to inherit from. To this end I've tried to implement different variations of the super() but admittedly I'm only guessing at this stage.

Updated to full working, I've cut out a few hundred lines

Run as > OK > Select an Image > Open > Crop (dual instances start running here)

App_R3App.py

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import io
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImageKivy
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.core.window import Window

__version__ = '0.1'


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def hl(self, image_address):
            self.new_image_address = image_address # for the sake of this
            self.callback_image(self.new_image_address, image_address, "Auto-cropped image")

    def callback_image(self, new_image_address_tmp, image_address_tmp, title):
        if new_image_address_tmp:

            third_screen = self.manager.get_screen("_third_screen_")
            new_image_address_tmp = [k.replace("\\", "/") for k in new_image_address_tmp]

            third_screen.callback_image(new_image_address_tmp[0], image_address_tmp[0], title)


class ThirdScreen(Screen, BoxLayout):
    # class attribute references
    image_size = (0, 0)
    image_pos = (0, 0)
    image_address = ""
    new_image_address = ""
    title = "Upload"

    rect_box = ObjectProperty(None)
    t_x = NumericProperty(0.0)
    t_y = NumericProperty(0.0)
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = NumericProperty(0.0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThirdScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def callback_image(self, new_image_address, image_address, title):
        sm.current = "_third_screen_"

        self.new_image_address = new_image_address
        self.image_address = image_address
        self.title = title
        self.ids.main_image.source = self.new_image_address
        self.ids.main_title.text = self.title

    def enable_cropping(self):
        # overwrite class attributes
        ThirdScreen.image_address = self.image_address
        ThirdScreen.new_image_address = self.new_image_address

        print("enable_cropping")
        sm.current = "_edit_image_screen_"

        return True


class EditImageScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("EditImageScreen")
        super(EditImageScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = None

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        print("on_pre_enter")
        self.layout = EditImageLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.layout)


class EditImageLayout(FloatLayout):
    color_button = ListProperty([1, .3, .4, 1])
    button_color = ListProperty([0, 0, 0, 1])

    rectangle_selector = ObjectProperty()
    text_size_rectangle = ObjectProperty()
    image_layout = ObjectProperty()
    bubble_buttons = ObjectProperty()
    bubble_buttons_undo_confirm = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("EditImageLayout")
        self.sm = kwargs.pop('sm', None)
        self.crop_image_screen = kwargs.pop('crop_image_screen', None)

        # This is where the problem occurs
        super(EditImageLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.rectangle_selector.bind(size_selected=self.on_change_size_rectangle_selector)
        self.rectangle_selector.bind(size_selected_temp=self.update_text_size_rectangle)
        self.bind(on_touch_down=self.bubble_buttons.hide)

        self.bubble_buttons.resize_button.bind(on_press=self.on_press_resize_button)
        self.bubble_buttons_undo_confirm.undo_button.bind(on_press=self.on_press_undo_button)
        self.bubble_buttons_undo_confirm.confirm_button.bind(on_press=self.on_press_confirm_button)

    def on_change_size_rectangle_selector(self, instance, size_selected):
        print("on_change_size_rectangle_selector")
        if not self.rectangle_selector.tap_not_draw_a_line():
            self.bubble_buttons.show()
        else:
            self.text_size_rectangle.text = ''

    def on_press_resize_button(self, instance):
        print("on_press_resize_button")
        self.image_layout.resize_image(width=self.rectangle_selector.size_selected[0],
                                       height=self.rectangle_selector.size_selected[1])

        self.rectangle_selector.delete_line()
        self.text_size_rectangle.text = ''

        self.bubble_buttons_undo_confirm.show()

    def on_press_undo_button(self, instance):
        print("on_press_undo_button")
        size = self.image_layout.old_size
        self.image_layout.resize_image(width=size[0], height=size[1])
        self.bubble_buttons_undo_confirm.hide()

    def on_press_confirm_button(self, instance):
        print("on_press_confirm_button")
        self.bubble_buttons_undo_confirm.hide()

    def update_text_size_rectangle(self, instance, size):
        print("update_text_size_rectangle")
        self.text_size_rectangle.text = str('({0}, {1})'.format(int(size[0]), int(size[1])))


class ImageLayout(Image):
    image = ObjectProperty()
    path_image = StringProperty('image_tmp.jpg')
    path_image_tmp = StringProperty('image_tmp.jpg')

    old_size = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("ImageLayout")
        super(ImageLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.path_image = ThirdScreen.image_address

        self.image = CoreImage(self.path_image,
                               data=io.BytesIO(open(self.path_image, "rb").read()),
                               ext=self.path_image[self.path_image.rfind('.') + 1::])
        self.source = self.path_image

    def resize_image(self, width, height, pos_x=None, pos_y=None):
        pos_x, pos_y = abs(Window.width - width)/2 , abs(Window.height - height)/2
        self.image.resize(self.path_image,
                         self.path_image_tmp,
                         int(width),
                         int(height))

        self.source = self.path_image_tmp
        self.pos = pos_x, pos_y
        self.old_size = self.size
        self.size = width, height
        self.reload()


class CoreImage(CoreImageKivy):

    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        print("CoreImage")
        super(CoreImage, self).__init__(arg, **kwargs)

    def resize(self, fname, fname_scaled, width, height):

        try:
            img = Image.open(fname)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception: ', e)
            return

        img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        try:
            img.save(fname_scaled)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception: ', e)
            return


class TouchSelector(Widget):
    # Points of Line object
    Ax = NumericProperty(0)
    Ay = NumericProperty(0)
    Bx = NumericProperty(0)
    By = NumericProperty(0)
    Cx = NumericProperty(0)
    Cy = NumericProperty(0)
    Dx = NumericProperty(0)
    Dy = NumericProperty(0)

    # Object line
    line = ObjectProperty()

    # List of line objects drawn
    list_lines_in_image = ListProperty([])

    # Size of the selected rectangle
    size_selected = ListProperty([0, 0])

    # Size previous of the selected rectangle
    size_selected_previous = ListProperty([0, 0])

    # Size temporary of the selected rectangle
    size_selected_temp = ListProperty([0, 0])

    # Line Color and width
    line_color = ListProperty([0.2, 1, 1, 1])
    line_width = NumericProperty(1)

    # First tap in TouchSelector
    first_tap = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TouchSelector, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind(list_lines_in_image=self.remove_old_line)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch): # on button up
        self.size_selected = abs(self.Cx - self.Dx), abs(self.Cy - self.By)
        self.size_selected_previous = self.size_selected
        print(self.Dx, self.Dy, self.Cx, self.Cy)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.line_color)

            # Save initial tap position
            self.Ax, self.Ay = self.first_touch_x, self.first_touch_y = touch.x, touch.y

            # Initilize positions to save
            self.Bx, self.By = 0, 0
            self.Cx, self.Cy = 0, 0
            self.Dx, self.Dy = 0, 0

            # Create initial point with touch x and y postions.
            self.line = Line(points=([self.Ax, self.Ay]), width=self.line_width, joint='miter', joint_precision=30)

            # Save the created line
            self.list_lines_in_image.append(self.line)

            print("on_touch_down")

    def remove_old_line(self, instance=None, list_lines=None):
        if len(self.list_lines_in_image) > 1:
            self.delete_line()

    def delete_line(self, pos=0):
        try:
            self.list_lines_in_image.pop(pos).points = []
        except:
            pass

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # Assign the position of the touch at the point C
        self.Cx, self.Cy = touch.x, touch.y

        # There are two known points A (starting point) and C (endpoint)
        # Assign the  positions x and y  known of the points
        self.Bx, self.By = self.Cx, self.Ay
        self.Dx, self.Dy = self.Ax, self.Cy

        # Assign points positions to the last line created
        self.line.points = [self.Ax, self.Ay,
                            self.Bx, self.By,
                            self.Cx, self.Cy,
                            self.Dx, self.Dy,
                            self.Ax, self.Ay]

        self.size_selected_temp = abs(self.Cx - self.Dx), abs(self.Cy - self.By)

    def tap_not_draw_a_line(self):
        return (self.size_selected[0] == 0 and self.size_selected[1] == 0)


class BaseBubbleButtons(Bubble):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BaseBubbleButtons, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def hide(self, instance=None, value=None):
        self.opacity = 0

    def show(self, instance=None, value=None):
        self.opacity = 1


class BubbleButtons(BaseBubbleButtons):
    resize_button = ObjectProperty()
    cut_button = ObjectProperty()
    rotate_button = ObjectProperty()


class BubbleButtonsUndoConfirm(BaseBubbleButtons):
    undo_button = ObjectProperty()
    confirm_button = ObjectProperty()


class App_R3App(App):
    Builder.load_file('App_R3.kv')

    def build(self):
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        return True

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        return True

    def on_stop(self):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create the screen manager
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='_first_screen_'))
    sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='_second_screen_'))
    sm.add_widget(ThirdScreen(name='_third_screen_'))
    sm.add_widget(EditImageScreen(name='_edit_image_screen_'))

    App_R3App().run()
```

App_R3.kv

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<MyScreenManager>:
    FirstScreen:
        id: first_screen
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen
    ThirdScreen:
        id: third_screen
    EditImageScreen:
        id: edit_image_screen

<FirstScreen>:
    name: '_first_screen_'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Label:
            id: first_screen_label
            text: "Hi, I'm the home page"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "Okay!"
                on_press: root.manager.current = '_second_screen_'
            Button:
                text: "Cancel!"
                on_press: app.stop()

<SecondScreen>:
    name: '_second_screen_'
    id: file_chooser
    BoxLayout:
        id: file_chooser_box_layout
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button
            text: "Open"
            on_press: root.hl(file_chooser_list_view.selection)
        FileChooserListView:
            id: file_chooser_list_view

<ThirdScreen>:
    name: '_third_screen_'
    id: third_screen

    xx1: root.x1
    yy1: root.y1
    tt_x: root.t_x
    tt_y: root.t_y

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: third_screen_boxlayout

        Label:
            id: main_title
            text: root.title
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
        BoxLayout:
            id: image_box_layout
            # limits the box layout to the position of the image
            Image:
                id: main_image
                source: root.image_address
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)
            Button:
                id: accept_button
                text: "Okay"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.image_accepted_by_user(root.image_address)
            Button:
                id: crop_button
                text: "Crop"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.enable_cropping()
            Button:
                id: cancel_button
                text: "Cancel"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.manager.current = '_first_screen_'


<EditImageLayout>:
    rectangle_selector: rectangle_selector
    text_size_rectangle: text_size_rectangle
    image_layout: image_layout
    bubble_buttons: bubble_buttons
    bubble_buttons_undo_confirm: bubble_buttons_undo_confirm
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 0.2)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: Window.width, Window.height

    Label:
        id: text_size_rectangle
        pos_hint_x: None
        pos_hint_y: None
        pos: Window.width*.45, Window.height*.45
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
    ImageLayout:
        id: image_layout
        size: Window.width*.8, Window.height*.8
        pos: Window.width*.1, Window.height*.1
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint_x: None
        pos_hint_y: None
    TouchSelector:
        id: rectangle_selector
    BubbleButtons:
        id: bubble_buttons
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (200, 40)
        pos_hint_x: None
        pos_hint_y: None
        pos: Window.width*.4, Window.height*.1
        opacity: 0
        arrow_pos: 'top_mid'
    BubbleButtonsUndoConfirm:
        id: bubble_buttons_undo_confirm
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (200, 40)
        pos_hint_x: None
        pos_hint_y: None
        pos: Window.width*.4, Window.height*.9
        opacity: 0
        arrow_pos: 'top_mid'

<BubbleButtons>:
    resize_button: resize_button
    cut_button: cut_button
    rotate_button: rotate_button
    BubbleButton:
        id: resize_button
        text: 'Resize'
    BubbleButton:
        id: cut_button
        text: 'Cut'
    BubbleButton:
        id: rotate_button
        text: 'Rotate'

<BubbleButtonsUndoConfirm>:
    undo_button: undo_button
    confirm_button: confirm_button
    BubbleButton:
        id: undo_button
        text: 'Undo'
    BubbleButton:
        id: confirm_button
        text: 'Confirm'
```

Console output, aka what the code prints (you can see that ImageLayout and CoreImage run twice)

```
EditImageScreen
enable_cropping
on_pre_enter
EditImageLayout
ImageLayout
CoreImage
ImageLayout
CoreImage
```

What I suspect is happening is that the super() is calling the base class EditImageLayout, the static elements of that base class are calling the .kv file and initating the ImageLayout and CoreImage classes from there. At the same time, "self" goes into action and does the exact same thing. This causes trouble later on when I implement on_touch_down over it (on_touch_down then appears twice, etc. )

[image: Output]

Comment: Why do you say that a duplicate instance has been created? I do not see any problem, you could show proof of what you point out.

Comment: Sure, I tried to elabourate. My terminology might not be up to scratch, apologies.

Comment: whats is the meaning of *Console output*?

Comment: What the code prints

Comment: you can provide a [mcve], I think the other call is given elsewhere

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to pear it down to a manageable size and format.

Comment: Full working file included, I've removed several hundred lines to make it easy without removing the core elements

Comment: I get: `EditImageScreen` `enable_cropping`
`on_pre_enter`
`EditImageLayout`
`ImageLayout`
`CoreImage`. could you show me an image of your console

Comment: Added. The warnings don't normally appear, it's likely due to the shortened program.

Comment: I have asked for an MCVE, if your code does not reproduce the problem it is not an MCVE, please take the time and provide what I have asked for to help you and thus save us time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

ImageLayout and CoreImage were called twice.

> ```
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is available
> enable_cropping
> on_pre_enter
> EditImageLayout
> ImageLayout
> CoreImage
> ImageLayout
> CoreImage
> [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

## Root Cause

The double calls to ImageLayout and CoreImage were due to two kv files, `App_R3.kv` and `app_r3.kv` present as shown in the screen shots below. In the application, the app class is `App_R3App(App):` and it is using `Builder.load_file('App_R3.kv')` to load kv code into application.

[image: Img01 - Two kv files, App_R3.kv and app_r3.kv]

## Solution

Remove kv file, `app_r3.kv`. In the example, we renamed it to `app_r3-off.kv`

[image: Img02 - No duplicate calls to ImageLayout and CoreImage]

[Kv language » How to load KV](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

> There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:
>
> **By name convention:**
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> ```
> MyApp -> my.kv
> ```
>
> If this file defines a Root Widget it will be attached to the App’s
>   root attribute and used as the base of the application widget tree.
>
> **By Builder:**
>
> You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If this string
>   or file defines a root widget, it will be returned by the method:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_string(kv_string)
> ```

## Recommendations

Since class rule, `<MyScreenManager>:` is defined in your kv file, you should use it rather than define `sm = ScreenManager()` in your Python code. On top of that, keep the view/design separate.

### kv file

Add missing class rule for *EditImageScreen*.

```
<EditImageScreen>:
    name: '_edit_image_screen_'

<EditImageLayout>:
```

### Python code

1. Add class definition for *MyScreenManager*
2. In `build()` method, replace `return sm` with `return MyScreenManager()`
3. Before `App_R3().run()`, remove all references to `sm`
4. Since each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used. In `callback_image()` and `enable_cropping()` methods, replace `sm.current` with `self.manager.current`
5. In `__init__()` method of `EditImageLayout()` class, remove `self.sm = kwargs.pop('sm', None)`. If you need to access the root/ScreenManager, use `sm = App.get_running_app().root`

#### Snippet

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
...
    def callback_image(self, new_image_address, image_address, title):
        self.manager.current = "_third_screen_"

        self.new_image_address = new_image_address
...
    def enable_cropping(self):
        ...
        print("enable_cropping")
        self.manager.current = "_edit_image_screen_"
...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("EditImageLayout")
        self.crop_image_screen = kwargs.pop('crop_image_screen', None)

...
class App_R3App(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App_R3App().run()
```

[ScreenManager » Basic Usage](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> Each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the
>   instance of the ScreenManager used.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a fresh look at this in the morning and also offer a bounty reward for such a detailed and insightful post.